# Creating a new list from an old list

Tags: list

Okay, so I've been wracking my brain trying to think of how to go about this and this question is just a simplified version of what I'm really trying to do but it all boils down to this.

I have a list:
lst = ['0', '53', '2', '4', '44', '5', '8', '11']

and '0' is the first item. I want the output to be:
lst = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

so I want the '2' from the first list, to become '1' in the second list.
'4' in the first list to become '2' in the second list.
'5' in the first list to become '3' in the second list.
'8' in the first list to become '4' in the second list.
'11' in the first list to become '5' in the second list.
'44' in the first list to become '6' in the second list.
and '53' in the first list to become '7' in the second list.

but I can't just manually change each one, it has to be automated and change each one by itself, like by using a loop or something

help i've literally been trying to figure this out for hours now and it seems so simple but i can't figure it out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def function(x):
    lstnew = []
    count = 0
    for e in x:
        lst.append(count)
        count +=1
    return lstnew

function(lst)
```

Comment: No, sorry, I messed up, i edited it, but i'm not trying to just half them, sorry, iworded it wrong

Comment: Based on the OP's edited question, it looks like you just need to return a list of the same length as the source with incremental values. And it seems the incremental value should start with the first value in the source list.

Comment: right, edited to include a list instead of dictionary